# Use Java String.replaceFirst for replacing strings containing special regex characters

Tags: java, html, replace

For splitting a string of HTML-sourcecode into it's parts, I have written a method that takes the next desired part of the string, copies it into a list of strings and removes the occurence in the string afterwards.
For the removal, I am using `text.replaceFirst(s, "")`.

Unfortunately, the provided HTML-Code contains regex meta chars like '|', resulting in only a partial removal of the characters I have already copied.

I really don't want to try to prefix all possibly problematic symbols with a backslash for escaping as it is tedious work and prone to mistakes.

Is there a possibility to replace only the first occurence of a string in another string without having to worry about such characters?

Example:

```
String input = "<title>text | more</title>";
String[] expected = ["<title>", "text | more", "</title>"];
```

I split for >, therefore get `"<title>"`, add this to my lists of results and call `input.replaceFirst("<title>", "");`, leaving my input as `"text | more</title>"`

I split for <, therefore get `"text | more"`, add this to my lists of results and call `input.replaceFirst("text | more", "")`, leaving my input as `"| more</title>"`, but I would have wanted my input as `"</title>"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the Pattern.quote() method to escape all regex meta chars in a string

```
String input = "<title>text | more</title>";
String[] expected = {"<title>", "text | more", "</title>"};

String[] parts = input.split(Pattern.quote(">"));

for (String part : parts) {
    input = input.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(part), "");
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for replacements. You can directly split on lookarounds for `<` and `>`.

```java
String[] res = input.split("(?<=>)|(?=<)");
// [<title>, text | more, </title>]
```

However, it should be noted that regular expressions are not the best tool for parsing HTML. Consider using an XML parser instead.